# Replace double backslashes with single backslashes in a bytes object

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, character-encoding

I'm writing a program where I deal with bytes object. The program generates a bytes object (from a string) where parts of it is randomly generated (if I run the program twice, a section of the bytes object will look different, the other is always the same). The bytes object always include multiple double backslashes, and at one part of the program I want to replace them with single backslashes.

The problem I have is that sometimes I successfully replace the double backslashes, and sometimes characters in the bytes object become completely wrong.

My method of replacing the double backslashes with single backslashes is essentially using decode and encode, as has been the suggestion in posts with similar issues. The following example shows when this works as intended:

```
string1 = '\\xeb\\x97\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'
bytes_double_back = string1.encode(encoding='ascii')    # b'\\xeb\\x97\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'
bytes_single_back = bytes_double_back.decode('unicode_escape').encode('raw_unicode_escape')   # b'\xeb\x97\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

However, when running the program again, this time with a slightly different looking string, things go wrong:

```
string1 = '\\x3d\\x5b\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'
bytes_double_back = string1.encode(encoding='ascii')    # b'\\x3d\\x5b\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'
bytes_single_back = bytes_double_back.decode('unicode_escape').encode('raw_unicode_escape')   # b'=[\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Here bytes_single_back indeed gets rid off the double backslashes but the beginning of it is not correctly converted.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sometime the backslashes are real, sometime are just printed in your terminals because it cannot print raw characters. Save to a file, so you know if you have blackslashes, or just control codes. Just from output it is often impossible to distinguish boths

Comment: I have saved the variables to a file previously in my efforts to solve the problem to check this, and the backslashes are actually there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beginning seems to be correctly converted to me. Note that byte string does not contain only escaped hex code. Sometimes hexcodes are printable in ascii. `"hello".encode()` is printed `b'hello'`. Which is the same as `b'\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'` See `b'hello'==b'\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'`

So, in your case `b'\x3d\x5b'` happens to be the same as `b'=[`. Why python would print the long version when the short one is ok?

Then, of course, the rest, `b'\x01\x00\x00\x01...` have no synonym (there is no ascii char that represents `b'\x01'`)

Again, check `b'\x3d\x5b\x01\x00'==b'=[\x01\x00'`. Same 4 bytes in the same 4 bytes long bytestring. Just two ways to write that same bytestring.

So, in short, that is just the way a bytestring is printed on the screen. With `\x01` for bytes that have no ascii representation. With an escape for bytes that are ascii code of some charaecter that would need escaping, or directly as a single character, when that char is unambiguous.
For example, `b'\x27'` is by default printed as `b"'"` because 0x27 is ascii code of `'`. Likewise `b'\x22'` is printed `b'""` because 0x22 is ascii code of `"`. But `b'\x27\x22'` is printed as `b'"\''`. It uses `'` to enclose the byte string and then needs to escape the `'` char.

Comment: Great explanation! Do you have any suggestions on what to encode the string with instead of ascii to make this work?

Comment: @Hypherix I probably lack some context. Because my point was: it is already working. I mean, if your goal is the have the correct bytestring, then, good news, you have it. Or do you have a reason why you need to print it (I say "print it" because it is only when printing that it matters. In memory `b'\x3d\x5b'` is the exact same thing as `b\=['`. Those are just 2 bytes, the same). I was under the impression that your goal was to end up with a bytestring (the last line of your code is computing one).

Comment: @Hypherix. But maybe what you want is the representation of a bytestring (so a string. A text. But that is not at all what you compute). Is that so? Because it is only when deciding how to print those two bytes that you may choose to print it as `b'\x3d\x5b'` or as `b'=['`. And that information is not part of the bytestring. It is a printing choice. Again, even your comment (the one I am replying to) ask "do you have any suggestions on what to **encode** the  string with". Which also makes me believe there is a misunderstanding. That IS the encoding (...)

Comment: (...) deciding to print the 2 bytes 61 and 91 (aka 0x3d and 0x5d) as `b'\x3d\x5d'` or as `b'=['` is a decoding decision, not an encoding one (decode ≡ create a string representation from a bunch of bytes. encode ≡ create a bunch of bytes from a string).

Comment: The closest thing I can think of, if you really need to get the string (not the bytestring. Again, the bytestring `b'\x3d\x5b'` you already have it, even if it is displayed `b'=['` in the console) `\x3d\x5b`, is method `hex`. Once you have the byestring (and, again, you have it), `bytes_single_back.hex()` is a string with all the bytes in hexadecimal. But without the `\x`.

Comment: I am a novice in this field so it's probably me being unintentionally unclear. The reason I want the bytes object with only single backslashes, and not with the "unintentional"/unintended conversion of certain characters, is that I'm trying to create a DNS query message, and when there are double backslashes or an unintended character conversion, the DNS message doesn't make sense. That is why I want the "final product" with single backslashes and escaped hexadecimals. Hope it clarified somewhat, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Hypherix But there aren't any backslash at all in `b'\x3d\x5b'`. Not a single one, not a double one. That is a bytestring. Python console may show it with backslash, but that is just what python has to do when you ask it to show a bunch of bytes.

Comment: @Hypherix Maybe you could roll back a bit, edit your question an explain the context (with example). What are those byteobject in the first place. How you generate them. Then what you do with them (usually there aren't any "byteobject" in a DNS question. Only strings. That may represent some bytes).

Comment: Magically, I think I've managed to make it work. Constructing my DNS query message, I previously constructed parts of it step by step (first the query, then the headers). Each of these parts I converted from string to bytes following with the decode-encode procedure.

Comment: I changed it so that I piece the parts of the whole query message as a string together into one full message, and then I convert it to bytes followed with the decode-encode procedure. As you explained,, printing this bytes object sometimes sometimes shows "unintended" character conversions but the bytes object is still intact and, according to Wireshark, the DNS query messages work correctly. Sorry for making this comments section a discussion and for the unnecessary confusion. Thanks though for clarifying the issue for me (and inspiring a solution)!